# How can I install Data Quality Services on a Denali CTP 3 installation?

Tags: sql-server

I want to take a look at the Data Quality Services feature in the Denali CTP; I happen to have a clean Windows 7 virtual PC image, and have installed the CTP.

Running up the DQS client gave the error:

> The SQL Server instance that you are trying to connect to does not include an installation of Data Quality Services. To finalize the installation of Data Quality Services please run the DQS installer script.
>
> For more information please refer to the Data Quality Services installation guide or contact your administrator

So I promptly went to run (as administrator)
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\DQSInstaller.exe`

After a "while" the installer bombs out with:

```
[31/08/2011 11:49:50]      * Creating the internal_core schema
[31/08/2011 11:49:52]         - Registering Microsoft.Ssdqs.Infra T-SQL executable objects.
[31/08/2011 11:49:55] Msg 10314, Level 16, State 11, Server VIRTWIN7PRO, Line 1
[31/08/2011 11:49:55] An error occurred in the Microsoft .NET Framework while trying to load assembly id 65572. The server may be running out of resources, or the assembly may not be trusted with PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS or UNSAFE. Run the query again, or check documentation to see how to solve the assembly trust issues. For more information about this error:
[31/08/2011 11:49:55] System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'microsoft.ssdqs.core, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. Assembly in host store has a different signature than assembly in GAC. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131050) See Microsoft Knowledge Base article 949080 for more information.
[31/08/2011 11:49:55] System.IO.FileLoadException:
[31/08/2011 11:49:55]    at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
[31/08/2011 11:49:55]    at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
[31/08/2011 11:49:55]    at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
[31/08/2011 11:49:55]    at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
[31/08/2011 11:49:55]    at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
[31/08/2011 11:49:55]
[31/08/2011 11:49:55]
[31/08/2011 11:49:55]
[31/08/2011 11:49:55] ERROR - An error occured, check message above
```

Reading [knowledgebase article 949080](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/949080) implies that this error may occur is the version of the DLL being registered differs to that in the GAC (strictly, if they have differing MVIDs); but this seems *unlikely*.

Has anybody been able to successfully install DQS on Denali CTP3, and if so, did you have to do anything "special" to get it to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that if SQL Denali test patch 11.0.1515 has been installed, then you cannot install DQS without first removing the test patch. I did this via Control Panel, and the remove updates option, which *seems* to work, although I'd strongly advise anybody wanting to play with DQS to just not install the patch in the first place...